# How do I play a generated waveform as a sound in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs5

If I have a sound waveform stored as a ByteArray in actionscript 3, how would I go about converting this into a Sound object that can be played?

Note that the array is full of sound samples - a complete generated waveform. It isn't an array containing an mp3 or other compressed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written quite a few tutorials on sound synthesis in Flash, some of which are about wavetable synthesis.

The general concept is that you need to fill an audio buffer ( Sound object ) with audio data at a regular interval. A Sound object will dispatch an event when it needs audio data. The block of data can be anywhere between 2048 and 8192 samples. Below is some pseudo-code that might help you out. It will create an audio loop from the data in the array.

```
var readIndex:int = 0;
var data:Array = yourData;
var sound:Sound = new Sound()
sound.addEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleData );
sound.play();


function onSampleData( event:SampleDataEvent ):void 
{
      for( var i:int = 0; i < 2048; i++ )
      {
           if( readIndex + 1 > data.length )
           {
               readIndex = 0;
           } else {
               readIndex++;
           }

           event.data.writeFloat( data[i] );
           event.data.writeFloat( data[i] );
      }
}
```

As I mentioned, I've written many articles on working with sound in Flash. Here is one such article: http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/07/slice-tool-looper/

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't really have the answer but I got also very interested in this problem as I read you thread and [here](http://cambiatablog.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/as3-loading-sound-from-bytearray/) is what I found. Sounds like a lot overhead but very interesting solution.

I hope this helps!